# Open set in topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be base for a topology $\mathcal{T}$.

From two following definitions of *base* and *neighborhood* respectively, does it imply that $\mathcal{B}$ is uncontable?
Is neighborhood really similar to open set in $\Bbb R$?
Here base is said to contain each neighborhood of $x$, since *for each neighborhood* it is possible to choose a set from $\mathcal{B}$.

> $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for topology $\mathcal{T}$ iff $\mathcal{B}$ is a subfamily of $\mathcal{T}$ and for each point $x$ of the space, and *each neighborhood $U$ of x*, there is a member $V$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V\subset U$.

and

> A set $U$ in a topological space is **a neighborhood** of a point $x$ *iff* $U$ contains an open set to which $x$ belongs.

Comment: What is your definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: There is a topology with only two open sets (empty and all space), There is only one neighborhood (the whole space) and there is a base with only one element (the whole space).

Comment: @Quimey. Agree.

Comment: @SahibaArora For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_0$ in $(a,b)\subset \Bbb R$ such that $x_0-a < \varepsilon$ and $b-x_0 < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From two following definitions of base and neighborhood respectively, does it imply that $\mathcal{B}$ is uncontable?

No, even for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ . For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, write $B(x,\epsilon) := ]x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon[$ for the open ball centered at $x$ vith radius $\epsilon$. Now consider 
$$\mathcal{B} := \big\{B(q,\frac{1}{n}) \ \big| q \in \mathbb{Q}, \ n\in \mathbb{N} \big\}$$

$\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology, and is countable.